# Linux root directory and partition

Tags: linux, partition, directory, root-filesystem

[image]

We say that the Linux file system has only one root directory. Supposing we have more than two partitions on our computer, how can we say that the other partition is a sub-directory of the root directory?

Comment: Not just Linux, but all Unixes (including MacOS X), and NT (as used in Microsoft's XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10 and others). However NT also has the idea of multiple roots, to be backward compatible with CPM.

Answer (score 2):

> Tomas, new contributor

the syntax is simply `/folder/folder/folder/.../file`

you can have an almost unlimited number of subfolders... there technically is a limit and would depend on the file system such as XFS, EXT3, EXT4, BTRFS.

simply put, everything just starts at `/` and is known as the *root file system*

**Any folder** under `/` can be a mount point.

do a `df -h` at the prompt and you will see something like

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc3       558G  111G  447G  20% /
tmpfs           252G   33M  252G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       5.0T  4.8T  190G  97% /data
/dev/sdc2       950M  234M  717M  25% /boot
/dev/sdc1       190M   10M  180M   6% /boot/efi

#############################################################



my /dev/sdc  is my one operating system disk having 3 partitions
  partition 1 is mounted to /boot/efi
  partition 2 is mounted to /boot
  partition 3 is the root file system mounted at /
/dev/sda     is my raid-5 volume of 10 disks mounted to folder,
             that one partion under block device sda is mounted at /data
             I can mount this 5TB volume anywhere (which is not already a mount point) under /
```

`/etc/fstab` is the file that will show what gets mounted upon boot for example

```
UUID=5b503190-ba94-42ac-bd79-0e3dbef5     /             xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=e9f763e7-f9b7-469b-9a69-eefcbb8e     /boot         xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=A95A-1342                            /boot/efi     vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/e16528d8-ec26-4743-828a-c399b46e4a21    /data    auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

linux **requires** something to be mounted as `/`.  After that wherever any folder under `/` resides physically linux does not care.

Answer (score 0):

The running system (or more correctly a process in the running system) has a "root directory", referred to by `/`.  Each filesystem (mounted partition) also has a root directory, often inode 2.

The root directory of each filesystem may be mount on some directory of some other filesystem.  (OK, on Linux, you could multiply mount it, and mount it on a directory of itself, and mount parts of it.)

One problem you are probably having is that there are actually two distinct things that are a "root directory".  With some of the fancier options, it is not necessarily the case that the system's root directory is the root directory of a filesystem.

Another is that the term filesystem is both what comes from one partition, and the collection of everything mounted.